# NoReverseMatch exception in Django

Tags: python, django

Here is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^index/$',views.index,name="index"),
url(r'menu/$',views.menu,name="menu"),
```

and views.py:

```
def index(request,**kwargs):
     #some code


def menu(request):
     #some code
     url = reverse('index', kwargs={'msg': "Download Completed! Downloading took %.4f minutes.\nAverage Download Speed:%.2f Kbps"%(end,speed)})
     return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
     #some code
```

This gives me an

**error message**

> Reverse for 'main' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'msg': 'Download >Completed! Downloading took 0.2889 minutes.\nAverage Download Speed:581.53 >Kbps'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['index/$']

when I go to menu.

I am new to python and django. Where's the problem ?
Also is there another way to pass arguments to a view from another view?

Comment: Have you tried reverse("index/",...)?

Comment: @nneonneo yes, just tried, same error.

Comment: @Sonakshi, can i recommend something. The naming you use is very confusion. It would be better to follow some naming convention. `Main` should not be capitalize because it is not a class. URL `/index/` is usually the main view, so the view name should either be `index` or `main`, but the problem is the `/menu/` is having `main` view name. This is confusing, so please rename the `/menu/` URL to use a views called `menu` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Django `reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is a function taking `viewname`, and not a `/<url>/`.

So to fix this, you need to name your view,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^menu/$',views.main, name='main'),
]
```

And to call the `reverse` like the following.

```
def main(request):
    url = reverse('index', args=(), kwargs={})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

However, there is a shortcut [django.shortcuts.redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def main(request):
    return redirect('index')
```

> In the past you can reverse by providing the python path, such as `reverse('views.main')`, however it is considered deprecated in Django 1.8

Comment: Now the error states : Reverse for 'main' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'msg': 'Download Completed! Downloading took 0.2889 minutes.\nAverage Download Speed:581.53 Kbps'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['index/$']

Comment: @Sonakshi, please try the latest code, i have a confusion just now about the view name and the urls. It should solve your problem.

Comment: redirect works fine, but I need to pass the arguments as well.

Comment: @Sonakshi, ya, i'm just giving you an example, if you need to pass an argument you can just pass it as parameter. e.g. `redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Sonakshi, I also notice you didn't capture the URL. Try change the urlpatterns to use the following instead. `url(r'index/(?P<msg>\w+)/$',  views.index, name='index')`